# Updating Entity Framework 6 Database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update my database and insert values into one of the columns `"LongitudinalId"`, but as soon as I run the **update-database** command in my *Package Manager Console*, it gives me this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LongitudinalId', table
>   'TruckDbWcf.dbo.Chassis'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here is the code where I am trying to **insert** the data:

```
            context.Chassis.AddOrUpdate<Chassis>(x => x.Name,
                new Chassis { Name = "DAIHATSU DELTA V116", LongitudinalId = context.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First().Id },
                new Chassis { Name = "DAIHATSU DELTA V116 PLUS", LongitudinalId = context.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First().Id },
                new Chassis { Name = "DAIHATSU DELTA V58", LongitudinalId = context.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First().Id },
                new Chassis { Name = "FAW", LongitudinalId = context.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First().Id },
                ... //It goes on for about 100 more lines
                new Chassis { Name = "VOLKSWAGEN VW 24-250 LWB (D AXLE)", LongitudinalId = context.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH110").First().Id });
```

Now i've already checked that I am inserting data in **every single line** that requires the `"LogitudinalId"`, but I can't figure out why it's giving me this much trouble and throwing the error that I gave above.

I have also tried to delete the database as well as to delete the current data that's already in that specific table, but I am getting no where. If anyone can help, I would be very greatfull! :)

EDIT- Class where I create the table with the LogitudinalId:

```
public class Chassis
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? LongitudinalId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LongitudinalId")]
    public virtual StockItem ChassisLongitudinal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is Id a nullable type? One of them may be null. BTW as is your query is pretty inefficient, you don't need to search for item with stock code SCH100 multiple times (also a plain foreach over a string array will make your code much more readable).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will add the class where I create the Id. Please view the EDIT. Thank you :D

Comment: @Adriano Repetti - I will clean the code up with your advice, thank you!

Comment: Question: why ChassisLongitudinal property with ForeignKeyAttribute + LongitudinalId property instead of following convention Longitudinal + LongitudinalId properties (without any attribute, if Longitudinal is virtual EF can manage everything for you).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly (I'm quite new to EF6) I should just remove the ForeignKeyAttribute from my class? Will the connection between my two tables still be there or will EF create it for me?

Comment: If you follow convention: `Name` (virtual property for navigation) and `NameId` (for its ID) then yes. Note that you may also directly assign navigation property: `new Chassis { Name = "FAW", Longitudinal = context.StockItems.First(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100") }`

Comment: Ok so I removed the **ForeignKeyAttribute** and tried to update the database again, but now it's giving me this: _The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Chassis_dbo.StockItems_ChassisLongitudinal_Id". The conflict occurred in database "TruckDbWcf", table "dbo.StockItems", column 'Id'._

Comment: See [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725836/updating-entity-framework-6-database-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment49509337_30725836), you also need to follow _convention_, in your case rename `ChassisLongitudinal` in `Longitudinal` and keep `LongitudinalId` as is (of course you have to drop your existing DB).

Comment: I'm so greatfull for your help and input so far! I'm also so sorry for all the issues 0_o. Once I dropped the DB, renamed the **ChassisLongitudinal** to **Longitudinal** and... followed Convention, I tried to update/create the database again and I received the following: _Sequence contains no elements_ This is where I get stuck at the end of every different try of trying something new to fix my problem

Comment: Good! ;) It's because `context.StockItems.First(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100")` finds no elements: simply there isn't any element in `context.StockItems` with `StockCode` equals to `"SCH100"`. If it's something that may happen (`Chassis` may have not any `Longitude`) replace `First()` with `FirstOrDefault()`. Well it may also be because you dropped your DB and now `StockItems` is empty...

Comment: I think I just found the issue...somewhere in the 104 lines of code one of the **StockCodes** doesn't have the correct code, or like you said it has a code that does not exist. Thank you very much for all your time and effort Adriano!! How can I give you marks for helping me towards solving my issue?

Comment: thank you but don't worry, more than here to help I was here to chat! Happy coding! (if I can I give you a last small tip: replace that 104 lines of almost duplicated code with a foreach loop, it'll save you from this typos!)